# Inherent flaw to my process of android coding

Tags: android, debugging

So I am very used to creating python-ish scripts that have lots of functions and these functions reference each other all of the time. This seems like the natural way to do things for me (I am more of a math person than a CS person).

However, I have recently taken an interest in android programming and want to create a quote generator.

Essentially I have no idea what is wrong with my code would really love some pointers about what is wrong with it and how I can get better at android programming. I am currently working through the big nerd ranch guide to android programming and I understand it is a good book.

This is my MainActivity.java

```
    package com.example.alex.donaldtrump;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button generate_button;
    TextView textView;
    quote_generation quote_generation= new quote_generation();
    String quote_gen = quote_generation.returnable();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String a= quote_gen;

        generate_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.generate_button);

        textView= (textView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

        generate_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void generate_click(View view) {
                textView.setText(a);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }





}
```

My quote_generation.java code is here

```
package com.example.alex.donaldtrump;
```

import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Created by Alex on 8/13/2015.
 */
public class quote_generation {

```
Random rand= new Random();
Random rana = new Random();
Random runa = new Random();

private String[] quotes= {"I\'m a bit of a P. T. Barnum. I make stars out of everyone.", "You have to think anyway, so why not think big?", "Everything in life is luck.", "All of the women on The Apprentice flirted with me - consciously or unconsciously. That\'s to be expected.", "The point is that you can\'t be too greedy.", "Show me someone without an ego, and I\'ll show you a loser.", "Money was never a big motivation for me, except as a way to keep score. The real excitement is playing the game.", "I try to learn from the past, but I plan for the future by focusing exclusively on the present. That\'s where the fun is.", "You know, it really doesn\'t matter what the media write as long as you\'ve got a young and beautiful piece of ass.", "The concept of global warming was created by and for the Chinese in order to make U.S. manufacturing non-competitive.", "Listen you m-----f------, we\'re going to tax you 25 percent!", "When was the last time anybody saw us beating, let\'s say, China in a trade deal? They kill us. I beat China all the time. All the time.", "I will build a great wall — and nobody builds walls better than me, believe me —and I\'ll build them very inexpensively. I will build a great, great wall on our southern border, and I will make Mexico pay for that wall. Mark my words.", "The wall will go up and Mexico will start behaving.", "Our great African American President hasn\'t exactly had a positive impact on the thugs who are so happily and openly destroying Baltimore!", "The only kind of people I want counting my money are little short guys that wear yamakas every day.", "If I were running The View, I'd fire Rosie O\'Donnell. I mean, I\'d look her right in that fat, ugly face of hers, I\'d say, Rosie, you\'re fired.", "If you can\'t get rich dealing with politicians, there\'s something wrong with you.", "We build a school, we build a road, they blow up the school, we build another school, we build another road they blow them up, we build again, in the meantime we can\'t get a f------ school in Brooklyn.", "A certificate of live birth is not the same thing by any stretch of the imagination as a birth certificate.", "Free trade is terrible. Free trade can be wonderful if you have smart people. But we have stupid people.", " He\'s not a war hero. He's a war hero because he was captured. I like people that weren\'t captured, OK, I hate to tell you.", "One of the key problems today is that politics is such a disgrace. Good people don\'t go into government."};
private String[] nouns = {"the Chinese", "fetus concentration camps", "Crack babies", "Viking like corporate invasion", "Cecil the lion", "adult business transactions", "furries", "the great wall of Texas", "literally hundreds of foreigners", "Cancer", "fucking leeches with pre-existing conditions", "racist cunts", "warm, fluffy puppies", "sleepy-time tea", "that one black guy I know", "eleven trades", "like, so many transactions", "the flaming skull of baby Jesus", "fetii", "hypothetical non-Caucasian Christians", "my muse", "additional pylons", "buried treasure off the coast of Zanzabar", "supposed war heroes", "so many foriegn rapists you guys", "orphanages that aren\'t returning a fucking profit", "this guy I know named Chad", "even more damn orphans", "the smiles on little babies\' faces", "stylish comb-overs", "comb-overs for every man, woman, and child", "an amendment legalizing comb-over rights", "making other hairstyles illegal" };

private int quotes_length=quotes.length;
private int noun_length=nouns.length;

int randomNum = rand.nextInt((quotes.length ) + 1);
int ran=rana.nextInt();
int run=runa.nextInt();

public int getRandomNum() {
    return randomNum;
}

public String returnable() {

    if ((randomNum % quotes_length) == 0) {
        String b = "I'm a bit of a" + nouns[ran % noun_length] + "I make" + nouns[run % noun_length] + "out of everyone";
        return b;
    } else if (randomNum % quotes_length == 1) {
        String c = "You have to think anyway, so why not think" + nouns[run % noun_length];
        return c;
    } else if (randomNum % quotes_length == 2) {
        String d = "Everything in life is" + nouns[run % noun_length];
        return d;
    } else if (randomNum % quotes_length == 3) {
        String e = "All of the women on The Apprentice flirted with me - consciously or unconsciously. That\'s to be expected.";
        return e;
    } else if (randomNum % quotes_length == 4) {
        String f = "The point is that you can\'t be too greedy.";
        return f;
    } else if (randomNum % quotes_length == 5) {
        String g = "Show me someone without an ego, and I\'ll show you a loser.";
        return g;
    } else if (randomNum % quotes_length == 6) {
        String h = "Money was never a big motivation for me, except as a way to keep score. The real excitement is playing the game.";
        return h;
    } else if (randomNum % quotes_length == 7) {
        String i = "I try to learn from the past, but I plan for the future by focusing exclusively on the present. That\'s where the fun is.";
        return i;
    } else if (randomNum % quotes_length == 8) {
        String j = "You know, it really doesn\'t matter what the media write as long as you\'ve got a young and beautiful piece of ass.";
        return j;
    } else if (randomNum % quotes_length == 9) {
        String k = "The concept of global warming was created by and for the Chinese in order to make U.S. manufacturing non-competitive.";
        return k;
    } else if (randomNum % quotes_length == 10) {
        String l = "Listen you m-----f------, we\'re going to tax you 25 percent!";
        return l;
    } else if (randomNum % quotes_length == 11) {
        String m = "When was the last time anybody saw us beating, let\'s say, China in a trade deal? They kill us. I beat China all the time. All the time.";
        return m;
    } else if (randomNum % quotes_length == 12) {
        String n = "I will build a great wall — and nobody builds walls better than me, believe me —and I\'ll build them very inexpensively. I will build a great, great wall on our southern border, and I will make Mexico pay for that wall. Mark my words.";
        return n;
    } else if (randomNum % quotes_length == 13) {
        String o = "The wall will go up and Mexico will start behaving.";
        return o;
    } else if (randomNum % quotes_length == 14) {
        String p = "Our great African American President hasn\'t exactly had a positive impact on the thugs who are so happily and openly destroying Baltimore!";
        return p;
    } else if (randomNum % quotes_length == 15) {
        String q = "The only kind of people I want counting my money are little short guys that wear yamakas every day.";
        return q;
    } else if (randomNum % quotes_length == 16) {
        String r = "If I were running The View, I'd fire Rosie O\'Donnell. I mean, I\'d look her right in that fat, ugly face of hers, I\'d say, Rosie, you\'re fired.";
        return r;
    } else if (randomNum % quotes_length == 17) {
        String s = "If you can\'t get rich dealing with politicians, there\'s something wrong with you.";
        return s;
    } else if (randomNum % quotes_length == 18) {
        String t = "We build a school, we build a road, they blow up the school, we build another school, we build another road they blow them up, we build again, in the meantime we can\'t get a f------ school in Brooklyn.";
        return t;
    } else if (randomNum % quotes_length == 19) {
        String u = "A certificate of live birth is not the same thing by any stretch of the imagination as a birth certificate.";
        return u;
    } else if (randomNum % quotes_length == 20) {
        String v = "Free trade is terrible. Free trade can be wonderful if you have smart people. But we have stupid people.";
        return v;
    } else if (randomNum % quotes_length == 21) {
        String w = " He\'s not a war hero. He's a war hero because he was captured. I like people that weren\'t captured, OK, I hate to tell you.";
        return w;
    } else{
        String x = "One of the key problems today is that politics is such a disgrace. Good people don\'t go into government.";
        return x;
    }
}
```

}

activity_mail.xml is as follows

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:onClick="playSound"
        android:src="@drawable/angrytrump"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/quote"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/generate_button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="36dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Generate"
        android:onClick="generate_click"
        android:id="@+id/generate_button"
        android:layout_above="@+id/toast_button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/toast_button"
        android:layout_marginBottom="28dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="About"
        android:id="@+id/toast_button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You code post in incomplete.

Comment: I completed it, sorry, I was having problems dealing with the formatting

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question?

Comment: I am receiving the following errors and looking on stack overflow has not helped me:

Error:(29, 20) error: cannot find symbol class textView
Error:(31, 70) error: <anonymous com.example.alex.donaldtrump.MainActivity$1> is not abstract and does not override abstract method onClick(View) in OnClickListener
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Can someone help?

Comment: Well, that error message is pretty clear, your click listener doesn't implement onClick().  To fix that compile error, change generate_click to onClick.

Comment: [This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) also might help.

Comment: Thank you guys so much, however, I am still getting the
Error:(28, 20) error: cannot find symbol class textView
message. 
I don't understand what is wrong since I have implemented the textView the same way I normally implement these kinds of things.

Comment: @AlexanderSludds That's a totally different problem, I suggest you make a new question with it.

Answer (score 1):

This part of your code:

```
generate_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void generate_click(View view) {
            textView.setText(a);
        }
    });
```

The framework does not know what to do with the method `generate_click` - but when a click event occurs, it expects you to have this:

```
generate_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textView.setText(a);
        }
    });
```

The `onClick` method needs to be implemented so that you can perform actions when a click occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Since part of your question seems to be able style, here are some tips:

- Stop using underscores. Java likes camelCaseForSeparatingWordsInAVariableOrMethodName
- You don't need more than one `Random()`. One will suffice.
- What IDE are you using? Since you're just getting started, you should use [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html).
- Whichever IDE you use, take its advice. The issue @Jim pointed out in the other answer should never have happened. Android Studio, for example, will automagically stub out your inner classes (like the `View.OnClickListener`) that was giving you trouble.
- Your fields should be private unless you have a compelling reason for them to be otherwise.
- Oh, just read this: [Code Style Guidelines](https://source.android.com/source/code-style.html)

I just have to point out that this line here is like a crime against humanity:

```
quote_generation quote_generation= new quote_generation();
```

if `quote_generation` is the name of your class, rename it immediately to `QuoteGenerator`. It should look like this:

```
public class QuoteGenerator {
    // ...lots of amazing code!

    public String returnable() {
        // ...a whole heckuva lot of 'else if'-statements
    }
}
```

And then that war crime of a line I mentioned earlier would look like this:

```
private final QuoteGenerator quoteGenerator = new QuoteGenerator();
```

(a subtle side benefit of doing this is that now StackOverflow knows how to do proper syntax highlighting on my markdown. Also, note the `final` modifier. We'll come back to that.)

And now, this line:

```
String quote_gen = quote_generation.returnable();
```

Becomes:

```
String generatedQuote = quoteGenerator.returnable();
```

And you should put that in your `onCreate()` method. Actually, you shouldn't. It should be in another method. But it definitely shouldn't be hanging out free and loose with your member variables (fields).

Once you have that `String`, there's no reason to do this:

```
String a = quote_gen;
```

Because that's just redundant. But really, so is the `generatedQuote` line. Let's just get rid of that, too. Why not use your `quoteGenerator` directly?

```
generateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        textView.setText(quoteGenerator.returnable());
    }
});
```

Now, it was very important that I earlier declared `quoteGenerator` to be `final`, because I use it here inside an anonymous inner class (did I get that nomenclature right, guys? I can never quite remember...). Basically, if it wasn't final, then your anonymous, shoot-from-the-hip implementation of `View.OnClickListener` just wouldn't know if it could trust it. And so it would throw a fit (an Exception, and your app would crash). If it's `final`, then it knows it can never change, and everything is right as rain.